# é correto unir arquivos de áudio utilizando fwrite() em PHP?

Tags: php, captcha

Estou desenvolvendo um *script* de um *captcha* simples em *PHP* e me desafiei a conseguir gerar um arquivo de áudio para ajudar pessoas com deficiências visuais.

Não sabia ao certo como fazer isso, mas criei um arquivo de áudio para cada letra do alfabeto e chamei-o de *'nome da letra'.mp3 (exemplo: 'w.mp3')*, e, em um arquivo *PHP* chamado *'audio.php'*, designado para criar o arquivo de áudio final, eu peguei as letras do *captcha* e juntei o áudio de cada letra utilizando as funções `file_get_contents()` e `fwrite()`, nativas do *PHP*; para minha surpresa, funcionou exatamente como eu queria.

Minha pergunta é: apesar de ter funcionado, é correto fazer isso? Ler o conteúdo de um arquivo e escrevê-lo em outro é simples em arquivos de texto e similares, mas em arquivos mais complexos como áudios, tenho minhas dúvidas se é o ideal. Se sim, é recomendado?

**audio.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start(); //início da sessão
    $vetorLetras = str_split($_SESSION["captcha"]); //código do CAPTCHA
    $arquivo = "audios".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.session_id().".mp3"; //nome do arquivo a ser criado
    $f = fopen($arquivo, "a+"); //arquivo é criado
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        //a cada repetição o arquivo recebe o conteúdo do áudio de uma letra
        $x = file_get_contents("audios".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$vetorLetras[$i].".mp3");
        fwrite($f, $x);
    }
    fclose($f); //arquivo é fechado
    //força-se o download do arquivo
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"audio.mp3\"");
    readfile($arquivo);
    //arquivo é excluído
    unlink($arquivo);
?>
```

[Código fonte](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10EoKpg8eaX5L0bDTE6K8QBPskbks1yqO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Caro fernando, não faz sentido, a maioria dos arquivos tem um tipo de entrada/cabeçalho, teu problema nem tem haver com fwrite ou php, a questão é entender como funciona o formato do arquivo, no caso mp3, se fosse só mesclar as coisas seria OK, mas não é, por isso mesmo existem CODECs (codificadores/decodificadores) de formatos, no caso existe uma ferramenta que pode usar na maioria dos servidores (geralmente tem no repositório do seu servidor linux se não for shared ou então terá que pedir ao suporte para instalar) que é o FFMPEG que irá lhe auxiliar nisso...

Comment: ... mas ffmpeg e servidores não é escopo de pergunta aqui no site, portanto estou só comentando ao invés de responder, o que vai lhe resolver fácil é instalar ffmpeg e aprender a usar ele (é via linha de comando no php para executar uma linha de comando de outro programa use o `exec()`).

Comment: simm até que funciona... mas tem ressalvas, MP3 foi criado para ser frame independente, por isso é possível cortar o áudio diretamente sem fazer decode, se o bit rate dos seus arquivos não variarem OK, caso contrário vai existir inconsistências em cada cabeçalho, no final vc poderá ter um arquivo com informações erradas